# Does the question about PlaneSploit and Hugo Teso belong on the main site?

Tags: discussion

Was going to ask a question regarding lessons to be drawn from [Hugo Teso's exploit](http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=14733) of insecure air-to-ground comm links, but three considerations made me think it over:

- the question is going to generate quite a bit of off-topic discussions on TSA, DHS and FAA - not good for SE;
- I don't have the [file with Teso's presentation](http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2013ams/materials/D1T1%20-%20Hugo%20Teso%20-%20Aircraft%20Hacking%20-%20Practical%20Aero%20Series.pdf) (it must have been pulled off the free Internet rather quickly, gets 403 forbidden now), so I lack a few details for a good question;
- the question may be regarded as too localized (we cannot discuss every CVE!).

Would like to hear the opinions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we can do [What would one need to do in order to hijack a satellite?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6424/836), we can do this too. Also, I was able to download the presentation just now, so I guess you had a transient issue.

If I get a lot of noise, I can protect it. If I get lots of off-topic comments, I can delete them. If it totally doesn't work out, then I'll close it...

... but I encourage you to post and hope it does provide good fruit :)

Comment: Okay, tried again and seems the file IS available. Will read and post...

Answer (score 1):

This will depend upon the question.  Make sure you choose a question that can be reasonably answered and has answers that can be backed up with facts or evidence, rather than one that is likely to receive mostly personal opinion and debate.

"What lessons can be drawn from his presentation?" will be too broad.